# Unmatched [ in regex;

Tags: perl

When i run my code this one specific line causes issues. I'm pretty sure it is an easy fix but i'm very new to perl and unsure how to remedy it.

```
if (/^([.+\])\s*$/) {
```

the line in question. It's telling my the `[` is unmatched, hopefully fixing this is pretty easy. Thank you in advance for any solutions.

Comment: Can you add a short script we can execute that will produce your error?

Comment: The script isn't close to being done yet unfortunately im troubleshooting parts at a time. Ive looked it up and I think it has to do with the placement of the slashes / in the code line. I just am unsure where to put an additional / or \ to make it work.

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you trying to match an if statement?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you have syntax error ABOVE your `if` statement so please show several lines of you code

Comment: `if (/^([.+\])\s*$/) {` closing sq. bracket contains escape `slash \\` however opening sq. bracket doesn't why?

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: @gangabass: There is a syntax error in that regex pattern; why should there be another one?

Comment: You're right! May be I missed it...

Answer (score 2):

The regex has only the opening bracket of a [character class](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-character-classes) `[...]`, since the other bracket is escaped, `\]`, thus specifying the literal `]` character. This is a syntax error and it is precisely what the error message says.

If you want to match any characters inside the literal brackets escape that first one

```
/^( \[ .+ \] )\s*$/x
```

This matches a string with all characters inside a pair of literal `[]`, possibly followed by spaces. Note that this may include nested `[]` — since `+` is ["greedy"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) the `.+\]` matches as much as it can, so up to the very last `]` in the string (and the bracket). If this is not desired use `.+?\]` which matches up to the first `]` (and the bracket).  Thanks to [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) for a comment.

I use the `/x` modifier since with it spaces are ignored and so may be used for readability.

Or you wanted the character class, in which case the closing bracket shouldn't be escaped

```
/^( [.+] )\s*$/x
```

This matches a string with only a period `.` or a plus `+`, and possible trailing spaces. (The `.` and `+` have no special meaning inside a character class.)

---

Another guess is that you wanted to match either a `.` or a `+` or a `\`, in which case the backslash itself need be escaped

```
/^( [.+\\] )\s*$/x
```

as addressed in the [answer by Zan Lynx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50431394/4653379).

The `\`  is one of the few characters which [have a special meaning](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Bracketed-Character-Classes)
 inside a character class.

Please try to specify all relevant information in a question, intent in the first place.

Comment: Other possible meanings for the OP's code are `[.+\\]` or perhaps `\[.+?\]`.   *"This matches a string with only periods . and/or pluses `+`"* should be "... only a period or a plus".   And I think you should explain the `/x` modifier rather than just putting it out there.

Answer (score 1):

You escaped your closing bracket by writing it like `\]`. If you want a back-slash in your character class, use two.

Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;

while(<>) {
        chomp;
        if (/^([.+\\])\s*$/) {
                print "matched\n";
        }
}
```